# Samba daemon does not work as systemd service, but works in foreground

Tags: ubuntu, samba, systemd

I am running a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 and having troubles with smbd. `service smbd status` tells me that smbd should be running:

```
   ● smbd.service - LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/smbd; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Die 2016-10-18 17:35:23 CEST; 2s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 24218 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/smbd stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 21980 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/smbd reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 25190 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/smbd start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Okt 18 17:35:22 speedy systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)...
Okt 18 17:35:23 speedy smbd[25190]:  * Starting SMB/CIFS daemon smbd
Okt 18 17:35:23 speedy smbd[25190]:    ...done.
Okt 18 17:35:23 speedy systemd[1]: Started LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd).
```

and this can be verified by `ps axf | grep smbd`:

```
25356 pts/2    S+     0:00  |   \_ grep --color=auto smbd
19915 ?        Ss     0:08      \_ /usr/sbin/smbd -D
19919 ?        S      0:00          \_ /usr/sbin/smbd -D
```

However, netstat -tpln | grep "smbd" returns nothing and also nmap shows "closed" on ports 139 and 445.

What I tried so far is activating these options in /etc/samba/smb.conf, but it doesn't help:

interfaces = enp2s0
bind interfaces only = true

If I start Samba in foreground using `/usr/sbin/smbd -F`, it works. I can then connect from another machine to the server and exchange files.

I have no clue that there might be wrong or how I could track down the problem.

Best regards,

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the same issue, in my case the problem was that another issue of smbd was running in a docker container, which was detected by start-stop-daemon, so it wouldn't start the service. In this case, I've changed this line in the file `/etc/init.d/smbd`:

```
 if ! start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --exec /usr/sbin/smbd -- -D ; then
```

to:

```
 if ! start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --pidfile /var/run/samba/smbd.pid --exec /usr/sbin/smbd -- -D ; then
```

This way it starts smbd if it's pid file does not exist.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! I have smbd running in LXC containers which seems to cause the same effect than you experience with docker.